# SQL: GROUP BY with one column

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table like this:

```
name    id1     id2     id3     id4
Mark    aaa     null    null    null
Mark    null    bbb     null    null
Mark    null    null    null    null
John    null    null    eee     null
John    ccc     null    null    null
John    null    ddd     null    null
John    null    null    null    null
```

So, I have 5 columns as, name, id1, id2, id3 and id4 -all are string values. I need to go for a GROUP BY for name only; which will have all the values except null values. So the final output will be something like this:

```
    name    id1     id2     id3     id4
    Mark    aaa     bbb     null    null
    John    ccc     ddd     eee     null
```

Can anyone please help me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MAX`:

```
SELECT
    name,
    MAX(id1) AS id1,
    MAX(id2) AS id2,
    MAX(id3) AS id3,
    MAX(id4) AS id4
FROM tbl
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: id1~id4 are string values; can I use max in that case?

Comment: Yes, you can. `z` > `a`.

Comment: Isn't this missing the GROUP BY?

Comment: @AntDC Thanks for pointing that out. Left out in the copy-paste.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
select 
  name,
  max(id1) id1,
  max(id2) id2,
 max(id3) id3,
  max(id4) id4
from
(
  select name, id1, id2, id3, id4,
    row_number() over(partition by name
                      order by name) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

Max on string... Z is greater than A. Any string is greater than null.
Don't forget the GROUP BY

```
create table #test(
name varchar(10),
id1 varchar(10),
id2 varchar(10),
id3 varchar(10),
id4 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #test SELECT 'Mark', 'aaa', null, null, null;
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 'Mark', null, 'bbb', null, null;
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 'Mark', null, null, null, null
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 'John', null, null, 'eee', null
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 'John', 'ccc', null, null, null
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 'John', null, 'ddd', null, null
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 'John', null, null, null, null

SELECT
    name,
    MAX(id1) AS id1,
    MAX(id2) AS id2,
    MAX(id3) AS id3,
    MAX(id4) AS id4
FROM #test
Group By name

drop table #test
```